# What is the event that will trigger click release-Javascript/Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to highlight a  element on click and on release of click event anywhere on the page I want to de-highlight the same  element:

fidde:
https://jsfiddle.net/3jvpg9t1/2/

code:

```
    class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeState: false
    };
  }
onmouseup() {
    this.setState({active: false});
}
onClick() {
    this.setState({active:true});
}
  render() {
  const bgcolor = this.state.active ? "#e9e9e9" :""
    return <div>
    <span style={{backgroundColor: bgcolor}}onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} onMouseUp={this.onmouseup.bind(this)}>helo world</span>
    {this.state.active &&
    <select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select>}
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

but for some reason I'm not getting the event that will trigger when the mouse click is release.
I tried: `onMouseUp, onBlur`

any ideas?

Comment: `onClick` will get fired after `onMouseUp`,  so your `onMouseUp` is getting triggered and it's setting the active to false, but then the `onClick` is triggered putting it back to true.  Try putting `console.log` in each event handler to see this happen.

Comment: my bad, apologies, I shoujld have added this extension. Wht im trying to do is when I click on the element a dropdown opens and the highlight shd stay, asa I click anywhere else the dd and the highlight should not be shown

Comment: `bind` vs arrow functions

Comment: I guess the mouseup event is incorrect for a click release. when I click on the <span> element, first the mouseup is fired and then the onclick, which is fine since I get the active to true, but when I click anywhere outside, no event gets triggered

Comment: @user1234, then use `onBlur` on the `select`

Comment: its not only the select that I want to hide, its also the bg color I want to de-highight, onBlur does not help either way, I have tried as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: The `mouseup` event occurs when you release the mouse button. What you need is a second click handler that handles a click on the document. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/q7xzr9cg/

Comment: thanks @ChrisG, the bgcolor gets de-highlighted when I click outside the element, just a qq: is there a tweak when even if I click back on the element, it'll de-highlight the bgcolor

Comment: Yes, just exit the click handler if `this.state.active` is already `true`. I updated the fiddle.

Comment: awesome @ChrisG. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never found a good way of doing this with just React, so I've fallen back on vanilla JS event listeners.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', this.handleBodyClick);
```

This will listen for a click on the body and will fire off the function which will set the active state to false.

Here it is in action: https://jsfiddle.net/sq2ajn8o/30/

If you want to have the active state toggle on click you should use a function that does something like this:

```
handleClick() {
  const { activeState } = this.state;
  this.setState({ activeState: !activeState });
}
```

If the active state is true, it will change to false and vice versa.

Comment: hi @Andrew Dibble: thanks for the pure js answer, this helped me another scenario, could you also please suggest a way when clicked on the same element, how to de-highlight the bgcolor?

Comment: @user1234, I've updated my response to answer this question.

Comment: hmm, thats confusing, coz when the user clicks on the <span> element (which is in active state), the handleBodyClick() (which has activeState: false) gets called first and then handleClick() (which negates false and return true) in turn the state being still active. something like: https://jsfiddle.net/zx0m4uwd/1/

Comment: You should add a class to those span elements so that the handleBodyClick will only change the state if you click on anything BUT that span element, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/oqtp1ye4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onMouseUp` and `onMouseDown` events.

The code below just simulates a button-press animation :)

```
<div
  className="cursor-pointer"
  onMouseUp={() => setHamburgerSize(30)}
  onMouseDown={() => setHamburgerSize(25)}
>
  <PiHamburgerLight size={hamburgerSize} />
</div>
```